# aws with an external rabbitmq broker

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq

We have a provider that wants to relay information information through RabbitMQ.

Our system is completely on AWS and we runs on managed services.  Example API Gateway, Lambda and DynamoDB, we would like to have a listener (consumer) of messages on the broker and we write into our DynamoDB.

Is this possible to do with some managed AWS Service?  I have googled a lot on this theme but only find things on installing a message broker within AWS.

It would be great is someone could point me to the correct direction.